# Extract width and height from images stored in Google Drive - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I use the following script to extract the image name and image URL of all the images inside a google drive folder.
It extracts this info into a google sheets doc. Is it possible to add the image dimensions (image height and width) into the script so it pulls into the doc aswell?

Script:

```
// replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = ‘FolderName1’;
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();

    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to retrieve the `width` and the `height` of the pictures that are stored in a specific folder in Google Drive.

- This info is located in [imageMediaMetadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) in the properties `imageMediaMetadata.width` and `imageMediaMetadata.height`.
- To retrieve this metadata you need to enable the Drive API and pass the `fileId` of your file as an argument:

  ```
  Drive.Files.get(fileId).imageMediaMetadata;
  ```
- Also store the data in an array and set the values directly to the sheet so you won't have to use `appendRow` iteratively which is very inefficient.

Last but not least, it is a good idea to check whether the file is an `image` regardless of each extension (`jpeg`,`png`). Otherwise, you will get an error if you the folder contains other types of files (spreadsheet documents etc.).

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the [getMimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getmimetype) contains the word `image`:

```
file.getMimeType().includes("image")
```

and only for these files, find the `width` and `height`.

### Solution:

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'FolderName1';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = [['name', 'link', 'width', 'height']];

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    let file = contents.next();
    if( file.getMimeType().includes("image") ){
      let name = file.getName();
      let link = file.getUrl();
      let fileId = file.getId();
      let dims = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).imageMediaMetadata
      let width = dims.width;
      let height = dims.height;

    data.push( [name, link, width, height] );
    }     
  }  
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
};
```

**Be careful!**

Make sure to **enable** `Drive API` from:

- **Resources** => **Advanced Google Services** (Legacy editor)
- **Services** (New Editor)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. It came up with an error 'Error 
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 1pkXfeSWPx2-89NeA4Y2un-J2zDdwgxIU
listFolderContents @ Code.gs:17     I have enabled the drive API

Comment: `Resolve a 404 error: File not found: {fileId}
The notFound error occurs when the user does not have read access to a file, or the file does not exist.` Please make sure you have read access to the files inside that folder . @Sophie

Comment: I do have full access, do you have any other ideas what it might be?

Comment: See details [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors). Can't reproduce your issue. I tested the code myself in a newly created folder which I put some images in there and it worked perfectly fine. You can do the same to see that it works. Is the folder a shared folder owned by someone else ? @Sophie

Comment: Yes the folder is ownder by someone else but i have access. Using the original script i posted works fine however this one doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunatly it says referenceError: Drive is not defined. I really appreciate your help though

Comment: @Sophie I will repeat myself. You said: `the folder is owned by someone else but i have access` . You need to have access to the **files** not just the folder. Make sure you have access to the **files**. Also `Drive is not defined` means you haven't enabled the `Drive API`.....

Comment: I replied saying I have enabled the drive earlier. No need to be rude? I said I appreciated your help many times. Thank you for your time trying to solve the question.  Yes, you may say the code gets height and width but as it is throwing errors then I haven't had a solution so far, hence why i was replying rather than a new thread. Will try seeing if changing folder ownership solves this. Kind regards.

Comment: I have access to all files inside. I uploaded the files into the folder myself. Drive API is still enabled.

Comment: @Sophie can you just create your own folder, put some images in it and test the code? In this way we can be sure that this service does not work for shared folders.

Comment: Yes sure, I have just created a folder in my own drive and it worked fine. It must be the issue with it being a shared drive which is causing the error. Thanks Edit: I am content manager access level in the shared drive

Comment: @Sophie I asked an expert in `GAS` and he suggested that if you have access permission to the file in the shared Drive then  `dims = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {supportsAllDrives: true}).imageMediaMetadata` would work for you. I **updated** my solution to catch such cases and you will be able to execute the code at least for the files you do have permission. So please try it out and let me know if it works. My friend also suggested that you could use [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp) library which does the same but it does not require extra permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [ImgApp library](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp) to retrieve the width and height of any image file in Google Drive.

```js
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
var res = ImgApp.getSize(blob);
var width = res.width;
var height = res.height;
```